# Jutifying content in flex after wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having a situation where I'm having a page title on the left side and rating number and stars on the right side. I'm trying to align all items centered once flexbox wraps. Once "Longer Page Title" reaches rating and stars and flexbox wraps, they should all be center aligned.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.title,
.ratings-and-stars {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.ratings-and-stars {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="title">Longer Page Title</div>
  <div class="ratings-and-stars">
    <div class="ratings">10</div>
    <div class="stars">**********</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I need to horizontally center content on mobile once flexbox wraps

Comment: You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) if you want a specific design for mobile, if you don't mind to always have your rating below the title, on screen width below x px

Answer (score 0):

The closest to your description i can think about is to play with margin & text-align and flex-grow for the title.

Below is an average demo.
However , you will need a mediaquerie set at a fixed breakpoint to decide when to wrap. See second snippet for a possible option

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.title {
  flex: 1;
}

.title,
.ratings-and-stars {
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:center;
  text-align-last:left;
}

.ratings-and-stars {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="title">Longer Page Title ////////////////////long_string_for_demo\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ .</div>
  <div class="ratings-and-stars">
    <div class="ratings">10</div>
    <div class="stars">**********</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Compromise with a mediaquerie (here set at 600px, use your own breakpoint)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.title,
.ratings-and-stars {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.ratings-and-stars {
  text-align: right;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .title {
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  .flex-container {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="title">Longer Page Title</div>
  <div class="ratings-and-stars">
    <div class="ratings">10</div>
    <div class="stars">**********</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

white-space is also a possibility for an average result:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}

.title {
 white-space:prewrap;
 margin:auto auto auto 0;
}

.title,
.ratings-and-stars {
  border: 3px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}

.ratings-and-stars {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="title">Longer Page Title //////////////////// long_string_for_demo \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ .</div>
  <div class="ratings-and-stars">
    <div class="ratings">10</div>
    <div class="stars">**********</div>
  </div>
</div>
```